# Private gem does not run on Heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku

I made a change to the right_aws gem. I saved this gem locally to: myapp/vendor/gems/right_aws-3.0.4. My application runs correctly locally.

I can push the ruby application to Heroku without errors. However when I run it, I get the following error:

:29:in `require': no such file to load -- right_aws (LoadError)
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in`require'
    from /app/db/db.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from build_transactions_db.rb:3:in`require_relative'
    from build_transactions_db.rb:3:in `'

My Gemfile contains this: gem 'right_aws', :path => "vendor/gems/right_aws-3.0.4/"

I get the same error with or without the trailing "/" in the :path.

I am running ruby 1.9.3-p374 in a non-rails ruby app. How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

You usually have to specify a version number when doing this:

```
gem 'right_aws', '3.0.4', :path => "vendor/gems/right_aws-3.0.4"
```

Hope it helps